# MongoDB and Mongoose: how to start populating children docs at a specific index of refs array?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Let's say I have a Book model with the following schema:

```
// Book schema
var bookSchema = new Schema({
  pages: [{
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Page' // ref to Page model
  }]
});
```

I have a `book` document for which

```
book.pages === [id1, id2, id3, id4, id5];
```

The thing is that I want to populate `book.pages` starting at `id3`, with a limit of two children documents populated per query.

I imagine the query would go something like this:

```
// Query
Book.findById(book._id).populate({
  path: 'pages',
  options: { 
    skip: elementsToSkip,
    limit: 2
  }
}).exec(function(err) {})
```

Elements to skip would be the number returned by

```
var elementsToSkip = book.pages.indexOf(id3);
```

The issue here is that I need to extract the index of the element of interest `id3` from `book.pages` (which has not yet been returned by the query).

Any ideas?
It seems like a pretty simple problem, but I have not been able to find any solution for this.
Hope you guys can help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
// Query
Book.findById(book._id).populate({
  path: 'pages',
  // Start at index of id3 in pages array
  .slice('book.pages', 2)
  options: { limit: 2 }
}).exec(function(err) {})
```

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing was the following (I am working with Promises, btw):

```
// Query
Book.findById(book._id).exec().then(function(book) {
  // Once Book.findById() is fulfilled with book doc
  var toSkip = book.posts.indexOf(id3);
  return book.populate({
    path: 'pages',
    options: {
      skip: toSkip,
      limit: 2
    }
  }).execPopulate().then(function() {
    // Do something cool
  }); 
})
.catch();
```

After the `Book.findById()` query is fulfilled, the returned document is accessed to extract the `indexOf` `id3` in `book.pages` array. Then `book.populate()` is provided with `skip` and `limit` options, where `skip` is set to the index of `id3` previously extracted. Finally `execPopulate()` is called to return a Promise that when fulfilled will return the populated `book` document.